# Compile GSL with O3 optimization level

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, gsl

My program heavily depends on the special functions from GSL and thus I would like to make it run faster, so I wish to compile GSL with higher optimization levels.

When I compile gsl, the default CFLAGS is "-g -O2" if I do nothing when I configure with "./configure". I am wondering why gsl is defaulting to an optimization level of O2 only since O3 is compliant to standards. I tried to compile and test with "./configure CFLAGS='-g -O3'", things worked. But I'm still not sure if everything would work.

Can anyone tell me why GSL is defaulting to O2 instead of O3? Would it be dangerous if I default to O3? Thanks!

Comment: Because o2 is meant to be the best performance without bloating code size. O3 means optimal performance without considering size at all. That's a design decision to choose o2 or o3. O3 won't break anything unless there are bug in the cod or compiler, but unfortunately there are (a lot of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimization level 3 is something that should only be used in case it is absolutely sure that it helps the library.

Since that level activates optimizations that may increase the size of the code a lot. This means in some cases it creates binaries that are even slower compared to a binary optimized with `-O2`. How ever that happens rarely. More likely are effects like a massively increased time to compile it, along with a increased binary size and a barely measurable performance change.

That `-O3` actually breaks something was pretty common some time back, but in the last couple of years I did not have a single case where `-O3` actually optimized something that caused the binary to break.

In the end the optimization level is something you can just test. Since `-O2` is the default, it is a pretty safe bet that this is the best settings for the compile operation in this case. If you feel like it you could try to compile it with a different setting to see if it makes any performance difference.

Interesting options are `-O3` and even `-Os`. I had cases in the past were both options gave improved performance over `-O2`.

So the real answer is: **Try it and see what happens.**